# MVC: How to separate Model from Controller

Tags: model-view-controller, web

Theoretically, I understand the MVC design pattern, but in real life I'm not sure about the Model and Controller.
Basically my question is: **What sort of code** should each of them contain?

From what I understand it might be something like this:

- **Model:** Starts a connection with the DB, contains abstractions (objects) that represent the data, ORM, plus some kind of an interface (functions) for the controller to get or change stuff in the DB.
- **Controller:** The main program. Starts the web server, starts an instance of the model's DB handler, does all the logic with the models objects.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Model**
How to work with the data (Create Read Update Delete at least).

**Controller**
Business logic or what to do with the data, your controller is the interconnection between the model and the view,  you get stuff from the model, you work with it and you pass it to the view, the user react (click of a btn) using an element in the view and it triggers an event that is cought by the controller, then the controller do stuff ... and basically you start again.

**View**
Visual representation (how you show the data), can communicate with the controller using events

**Example**

JS front-end app that shows a list of movie taken from the imdb API

**Model** -> js file with the API calls needed to get the movies

**Controller** -> js file with the calls to the Model , listeners to events from the view such as onclick on the pagination btns, rendering of the view when data changes.

**View** -> an html file with a list of movies and pagination btns

Comment: The model should only store the data. The controller is the one that should do the actual manipulation of the data.

Comment: Yes, what I described is more a service then a model (MVCS), but in most scenarios a service that provide data access is referenced as a model (MVC). and btw if you put all your data access methods in the controller you end up having fat controllers, instead a service will help you to share the same data access between multiple controllers.